# how make casting in htons and ntohs?

Tags: c, tftp

I have to use the two functions to convert the transmission data between client and server, the problem is that the data buffer must necessarily be uint8_t but ntohs and htons want uint16_t otherwise they don't work; so I have to bring the data into uint16_t and convert it back to uint8_t. but the data converted and brought to uint8_t are null, that is '0'. where am i wrong?
[image: the code:]

Comment: `uint8_t` is a single byte. Endianess doesn't apply to a single byte.

Comment: okay, the thing is, i can't use 2 bytes per character. how can I do?

Comment: sorry, I understand now

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the [tour] and read "[ask]". And please don't post source code as screen shot, any text in general.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use the `htons` or `ntohs` functions for a `uint8_t` variable, since it is only one byte. You `htons`/`ntohs` for `uint16_t` variables and `htonl`/`ntohl` for `uint32_t` variables.

Check this [link](https://www.gta.ufrj.br/ensino/eel878/sockets/htonsman.html), this might help you.